# Redirecting iostat output to a file

Tags: bash, awk, iostat

Why the output of iostat is not redirected to the file in the following command:

```
iostat -x 3 | awk '/sda/ { print $11, $12}' > /tmp/disk_utilization
```

Is iostat behaving differently than any other command?

Thx in advance

Comment: My version of iostat does not have a `-x` flag. I'm otherwise unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Same here on Mac OSX.

Comment: Kojiro and Mark, how are you guys stopping the iostat? ctrl+c? Are you seeing something in the file redirected to?

Comment: shelter, 2&>1 does not help.

Comment: Interesting, I'm experiencing the same thing. See nothing on stdout if I use `tee` either. Prints fine with no redirection.

Comment: By the way i am using: [root@myvm my_scripts]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Comment: @isaac.hazan apparently on OS X it just prints one line unless you tell it to poll. So this is a line-buffering problem?

Comment: @kojiro Yep, the output is buffered and is kept in memory until it is quit, which is when the file is populated with the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a count to tell the stream when to terminate( [man iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) ).  You're only adding the interval:

```
If the interval parameter is specified without the count parameter, the iostat command generates reports continuously.
```

When I try:

```
iostat -x 3 6 | awk '/sda/ { print $11, $12}' > outfile
```

the `6` tells `iostat` to stop after 6 iterations of 3 second intervals.  After the iterations `iostat` completes and I get an `output` file.

Alternatively, you could pick some expression to cause the awk script to exit.  When I try:

```
iostat -x 3 | awk -v max=10 '/sda/ { print $11, $12; max++ } NR > max { exit } ' > outfile2
```

I get just 3 lines in `output2` which makes sense because `iostat -x` produces about a screens worth of lines of output to the screen.

You could also force the awk to `fflush(stdout)` in each print cycle:

```
iostat -x 3 | awk '/sda/ { print $11, $12; fflush(stdout) }' > output3
```

and then close `iostat` with a `<ctrl+c>` from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that the pipe is buffered (probably `4k`), so if you wait long enough for the output to be flushed to the file it will no longer be empty.